# Efficient altering of variables in dataframe referencing previous row's value

Tags: r, data.table

I have a database like the following:

`df <- data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4),
                  num=c(12,12,12,28,28,17,17,7))`

```
  id num
1  1  12
2  1  12
3  1  12
4  2  28
5  2  28
6  3  17
7  3  17
8  4   7
```

I want to increment the value of num by 1 for every time there is another row for the id. I have the following code to do it:

```
for (i in 2:nrow(df3))  {
  if(df[i,1]==df[i-1,1]) {
     df[i,2]=df[i-1,2]+1
   }
 }
```

This would result in an answer like this:

```
  id num
1  1  12
2  1  13
3  1  14
4  2  28
5  2  29
6  3  17
7  3  18
8  4   7
```

This code works but my actual dataset to be worked on has 100's millions of rows and so is very inefficient. I have tried using the `lag()` function from `dplry` in different ways but have had no success. One such way was to get the id from the previous row on the same row to compare, here was my attempt:

```
df[,lag := shift(Id, 1L, type="lag")]
df[df$id==df$lag,2]<-shift(df[df$id==df$lag,2], 1L, type="lag")+1
```

This will obviously not run however. Any help to speed up my approach would be great! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df[, num := num + rowid(id) - 1L]
```

result:

```
#    id num
# 1:  1  12
# 2:  1  13
# 3:  1  14
# 4:  2  28
# 5:  2  29
# 6:  3  17
# 7:  3  18
# 8:  4   7
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `ave`

```
df$num+ave(df$id,df$id,FUN = seq_along)-1
[1] 12 13 14 28 29 17 18  7
```

Answer (score 0):

Another data.table approach in case you like an explicit `by`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df[ , num := num + 1:.N - 1, by=id]
```